# Convert Pandas DataFrame to bytes-like object

Tags: pandas, binary, pickle, bytesio

Hi I am trying to convert my df to binary and store it in a variable.

my_df:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
```

my code:

```
 import io
 towrite = io.BytesIO()
 df.to_excel(towrite)  # write to BytesIO buffer
 towrite.seek(0)  # reset pointer
```

I am getting `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'write_cells'`

Full Traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-be6ee9d9ede6> in <module>()
      1 towrite = io.BytesIO()
----> 2 df.to_excel(towrite)  # write to BytesIO buffer
      3 towrite.seek(0)  # reset pointer
      4 encoded = base64.b64encode(towrite.read())  #

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)
   1422         formatter.write(excel_writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=startrow,
   1423                         startcol=startcol, freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
-> 1424                         engine=engine)
   1425 
   1426     def to_stata(self, fname, convert_dates=None, write_index=True,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine)
    624 
    625         formatted_cells = self.get_formatted_cells()
--> 626         writer.write_cells(formatted_cells, sheet_name,
    627                            startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol,
    628                            freeze_panes=freeze_panes)

AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'write_cells'
```

Comment: I just test your code and working nice in pandas 0.23.4 under windows.

Comment: jezrael, when i print(towrite) it just prints `b''` why not `b'/x0/....'` I need to return the binary data, how can i get it

Comment: @pyd - I test it by `df = pd.read_excel(towrite)` and it return back DataFrame. Maybe some python issue? I test it under python 3.6

Comment: I resolved it by `towrite.getvalue()`, Thanks for your help @jezrael

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading pandas to newer version.

```
 import io
 towrite = io.BytesIO()
 df.to_excel(towrite)  # write to BytesIO buffer
 towrite.seek(0) 
 print(towrite)
 b''
 print(type(towrite))
 _io.BytesIO
```

if you want to see the bytes-like object use `getvalue`,

```
print(towrite.getvalue())
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00<\xb
```

Comment: Be very careful using the Excel format because it limits the [max number of rows and columns](https://superuser.com/a/366473/). Various other formats don't have such a limit.

Comment: use parquet instead

Answer (score 11):

#### Pickle

[Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is a reproducible format for a Pandas dataframe, but it's only for internal use among trusted users. It's not for sharing with untrusted users due to security reasons.

```py
import pickle

# Export:
my_bytes = pickle.dumps(df, protocol=4)

# Import:
df_restored = pickle.loads(my_bytes)
```

This was tested with Pandas 1.1.2. Unfortunately this failed for a very large dataframe, but then what worked is pickling and parallel-compressing each column individually, followed by pickling this list. Alternatively you can pickle chunks of the large dataframe.

#### CSV

If you must use a CSV representation:

```
df.to_csv(index=False).encode()
```

Note that various datatypes are lost when using CSV.

#### Parquet

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287485/). Note that various datatypes are converted when using parquet.

#### Excel

Avoid its use for the most part because it limits the [max number of rows and columns](https://superuser.com/a/366473/).

Comment: Thank you. I've been allowing users to save a dict of dtypes, but after reading this article I will switch to persisting in parquet https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-persisting-pandas-data-frames-in-csvs-f369a6440af5

Comment: Hi @Asclepius, what data is lost when exporting to csv? I tried googling it but couldn't find much.

Comment: @piedpiper Examples could be: floats vs ints, datetime formats.

Answer (score 6):

I required to upload the file object to S3 via boto3 which didn't accept the pandas bytes object.  So building on the answer from Asclepius I cast the object to a BytesIO, eg:

```
from io import BytesIO  
data = BytesIO(df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8'))
```